# how select multiple row using shift and Ctrl key in datagridview C#

Tags: c#, datagridview

[image][image]My requirement : In datagridview I need select row by clicking the row header and selected row should maintain until I will click the other row header also same time I should select cell too.

My Problem : I can't select multiple row using Shift and Ctrl key.

my code :

```
    List< DataGridViewRow> selectedRows = new List< DataGridViewRow>();

    void selectRows()
    {
        dataGridView1.SuspendLayout();
        foreach (DataGridViewRow r in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            r.Selected = selectedRows.Contains(r);
        }
        dataGridView1.ResumeLayout();
    }

    private void dataGridView1_RowHeaderMouseClick(object sender,DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridViewRow clickedRow = dataGridView1.CurrentRow;

        if (selectedRows.Contains(clickedRow))
        {
            selectedRows.Remove(clickedRow);
        }
        else
        {
            selectedRows.Add(clickedRow);
        }
        selectRows();

        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            if ((row.Index != e.RowIndex) && !row.Selected)
            {
                row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.White;
            }
            else
            {
                selectedRows.Remove(clickedRow);
                row.Selected = true;
                row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Blue;
            }
        }
    }

    private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            if (row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor == Color.Blue)
            {
                row.Selected = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Shift and Ctrl should work with DataGridView by defult. Did you change any of the properties?

Comment: No i didn't change anything..

Comment: You will need to provide a little bit more info here. We do not have the info to help you figure out what the problem is.

Comment: I want to select multiple row also maintain the selected row and when i select any cell also should highlight... here all are working fine but only issue is i cant select multiple row.. if i  select row use ctrl or shift key, the row automatically deselect..

Comment: So, while pressing Ctrl, you want to be able to select multiple rows when clicking row header, and select multiple cells when clicking on cell? So by the end you can have multple rows and multiple cells selected, while the selected cell could be on a different row than the selected row? If this is true, can you please provide the properties of your DataGridView? Because with the default setting in Visual Studio 2010, it should work automatically.

Comment: i think in my code only got problem.. can you please use my code??

Comment: I'm more concern about why you are trying to override things that already exist?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set your enable your datagridview's multiselect `dataGridView.MultiSelect = true;`

Answer (score 0):

Be familiar with using a debugger, you will be able to find out where the issue is.

You are clearing the selection in your loop

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
}
```

Rethink the if-else logic in it and you will see why. You are clearing your previous selections when you are not suppose to.